# Do we have any options to collect storage service operation logs in Azure using Rest API

Tags: java, rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Through the Windows Azure management portal, we can check the storage service operation logs. Is there any way to access those logs using REST APIs in Azure?

Since I can't post the image:

The steps to operation logs ->in the azure portal -> management services -> operation logs(date range) -> list out the operation performed such as VM created/deleted

Are there any Azure APIs to capture these logs programmatically?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of which operation logs you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing the steps. Yes, you could programmatically get this information. To do so, you would need to make use of [`Windows Azure Service Management API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx) especially [`List Subscription Operations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg715318.aspx). Portal actually makes use of the same operation.